# Is it possible to link a QGis project with an excel file?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, excel

I have an Excel file with coordinates and I have used this file to plot the coordinates in QGis. I was wondering if it was possible to permanently link the excel file to the QGis project, so that when I add new coordinates to my excel file, these will show up in QGis when I open the project.

Any ideas how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you are adding the data from Excel.  If you are importing your data as a Delimited Text layer, there is a little check box on the `'Create Layer from a delimited Text File`' dialog box (under layer settings) called `Watch File`.  Check this box and it makes QGIS watch for changes in the file.  In other words, as you add and save data in the text layer then it will update in QGIS (and not just when you re-open the project).  So you can save your data as a CSV and then could import that into QGIS and edit the CSV file and have the new points appear as you save them (you need to refresh the screen in QGIS to see them as the screen must redraw - use Ctrl + R).