# How to connect Excel file with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, excel

I am working with QGIS and I want to connect with Excel. I have exported attribute tables to Excel. Now I want to connect Excel with QGIS in the way that if I change a line dimension, it will be reflected in both the attribute table and in the Excel file.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not because the GDAL Excel driver is read-only:

http://www.gdal.org/drv_xls.html

The XYtools plugin allows to import point coordinates together with attributes, and export the attribute table only (if it works), but no real-time syncing.

You can save to CSV, and import that back into Excel manually. But this is not the kind of ODBC-like connection you are thinking of.

However, you can tell QGIS to watch out for changes in the underlying Excel file:

[Is it possible to link a QGis project with an excel file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91472/is-it-possible-to-link-a-qgis-project-with-an-excel-file)

Comment: Do you now any way? Is there any other way to do that?

Do i need a PostgreSql database to do that?
I want the syncing in real time.

Comment: If you store your GIS data in a spatialite database, you might access that with an SQLITE ODBC connection from inside Excel. See http://www.surfaces.co.il/spatialite-and-excel-on-talking-terms/ but I have not tested that. Older versions of Excel could read and write dbf format as used by shapefiles, but they gave up that support some years ago.