# Changing data (attributes) in .csv of data vector layer and QGIS automatically adopting this?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, csv, import

I have a .csv with data for 300 points: Each column on the .csv is a particular object and the cells define the amount that is available in each point.

If I need to change this amount, is it possible to change this in the .csv file in order that QGIS takes these edits automatically into its attribute table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if a.csv file is loaded into QGIS and you update the .csv file then the attributes of the layer will also reflect the changes:

A .csv file loaded into QGIS:

[image: Attributes of point layer]

Editing the .csv file with a simple text editor (I used Notepad):

[image: Editing attributes]

Save the edits and then load the attribute table again in QGIS to see the updates:

[image: Updated attributes in QGIS]

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you again @Joseph. I tried the same, but opened the .csv in Excel.

Comment: @KevinSuhr - That works too =)

Comment: not in my computer :( Not even with my text editor "text edit"...I added the .csv via _add vector layer_, _data based layer_. (maybe slightly different, my QGIS is german) Is that correct way?

Comment: Huh strange...If your "_data based layer_" option is the same option in English (_Add delimited text layer_) then it should work. Is your .csv file also loaded into QGIS or just added as a layer? Also, you should unaccept my answer as you are still having problems :)

Comment: when loading in the .csv use the 'watch' option http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91472/is-it-possible-to-link-a-qgis-project-with-an-excel-file