# QGIS simple link to external data

Tags: qgis, data, dynamic

I have a set of sensors at fixed locations across a landscape. Each is connected to an Arduino Uno board which is coupled to a WiFi board. New sensors get added occasionally and old ones stop working. I want to display the data gathered by each sensor, in (nearly) real-time, in QGIS, as a map of points with attributes displayed as (for example) colours of point symbols. The data value is read by each sensor every 15 minutes or so and thus I want to upload these values to QGIS and update my QGIS vector map of the sensor values at this interval.

The data themselves are very simple - a single real numerical value which I could convert and present as integer, ASCII text string, HTML, XML or pretty much anything else because I can convert them at the sensor end. Since I know the location of each sensor I can also include values of lat/long (for example) in the data each sensor URL presents to the world.

What's the very simplest way to get my data from the sensors onto a QGIS map which periodically gets the data and displays them?

Comment: Can you load your data into a postgresql database?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Yes I could. But I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible and this provides a whole host of functionality I don't need, at the expense of simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to save your data to a delimited text file (CSV) that you can periodically update/overwrite.  Load this file in QGIS tell QGIS to watch it.  See a similar but slightly different question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91472/is-it-possible-to-link-a-qgis-project-with-an-excel-file).

Checking the `Watch file` option will cause QGIS to watch the file for changes made by another application while QGIS is running (see [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd prefer to avoid the extra step if I can. Thus what I'm seeking to do is link each point vector location to a data value presented at the URL of each of my sensors - so the table of values in the QGIS vector file contains links which are addressed every 15 minutes or so to recover and plot new values, one from, each URL.

Comment: @D.Jordan I did this for wildfires was mentioned here using wget from a webservice but can be applied to sensors https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148812/pulling-a-csv-file-from-website-into-qgis-with-ability-to-automatically-refresh/148815#148815